# Mapping over a type-level list

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

I have a typeclass set up something like this:

```
class (KnownSymbol base, KnownSymbol quote) => FooPair base quote where
  pairVal :: Text

instance FooPair "USD" "ZAR" where
  pairVal = "USDZAR"

instance FooPair "EUR" "ZAR" where
  pairVal = "EURZAR"
```

Now I would like to be able to handle type-level lists of currency pairs as well. I came up with the following approach using primitive recusion over the list:

```
type Pair base quote = '(base, quote)

class Pairs ps where
  pairVals :: [Text]

instance Pairs '[] where
  pairVals = []

instance (FooPair base quote, Pairs ps) => Pairs (Pair base quote ': ps) where
  pairVals = (pairVal @base @quote : pairVals @ps)
```

Now I can do like this:

```
λ> pairVals @'[Pair "USD" "ZAR", Pair "EUR" "ZAR"]
["USDZAR", "EURZAR"]
```

However, this feels like a lot of work to do what is just `map` for value-level lists. Is there a type-level equivalent or some other way to shorten this?

Comment: I don't think you can do any better. Haskell's support for dependent types is somewhat lacking and awkward to use. Even so, this could be reasonably easy if you were working just at type level, but you also have a value to produce as you perform your type computation, and type classes are really the only way to do that.

Comment: That kind of dependent `map` function looks roughly like something sop-core and vinyl offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a little cleaner to define `pairVal` and `pairVals` at the type level using type families, and then separately think about demoting their results back to the value level.  The `singletons` package makes this pretty easy.

Until they add `EnableEveryExtension` to GHC, you'll need to enable a bunch of them, and add a few imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    AllowAmbiguousTypes
  , DataKinds
  , GADTs
  , OverloadedStrings
  , ScopedTypeVariables
  , TemplateHaskell
  , TypeApplications
  , TypeFamilies
  , UndecidableInstances
#-}

module Currency where

import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Singletons.TH
import Data.Text (Text)
```

Then, you can define type-level versions of `pairVal` and `pairVals` using Template Haskell and `promote`:

```
promote
  [d|

    pairVal :: Symbol -> Symbol -> Symbol
    pairVal "USD" "ZAR" = "USDZAR"
    pairVal "EUR" "ZAR" = "EURZAR"

    pairVals :: [(Symbol, Symbol)] -> [Symbol]
    pairVals = map (uncurry pairVal)

   |]
```

This already makes available the type-level `PairVals` function, so in GHCi, we can do:

```
λ> :set -XDataKinds
λ> :kind! PairVals '[ '("USD","ZAR"), '("EUR","ZAR") ]
PairVals '[ '("USD","ZAR"), '("EUR","ZAR") ] :: [Symbol]
= '["USDZAR", "EURZAR"]
```

If you want to get value-level results from these functions, like your original `pairVal` and `pairVals` functions, you can use the `demote` function provided by the `singletons` infrastructure.  For example, the following works fine:

```
λ> :set -XTypeApplications
λ> demote @(PairVal "USD" "ZAR")
"USDZAR"
λ> demote @(PairVals '[ '("USD","ZAR"), '("EUR","ZAR") ])
["USDZAR","EURZAR"]
```

If you want, you can write specialized versions of `demote` like so:

```
pairVal' :: forall a b p. (p ~ PairVal a b, SingI p) => Text
pairVal' = demote @p

pairVals' :: forall lst ps. (ps ~ PairVals lst, SingI ps) => [Text]
pairVals' = demote @ps
```

Note that these aren't promoted functions, so they go outside the `promote` call.  Then, then work exactly like your original `pairVal` and `pairVals` functions:

```
λ> pairVal' @"USD" @"ZAR"
"USDZAR"
λ> pairVals' @ '[ '("USD","ZAR"), '("EUR","ZAR") ]
["USDZAR","EURZAR"]
```

The full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    AllowAmbiguousTypes
  , DataKinds
  , GADTs
  , OverloadedStrings
  , ScopedTypeVariables
  , TemplateHaskell
  , TypeApplications
  , TypeFamilies
  , UndecidableInstances
#-}

module Currency where

import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Singletons.TH
import Data.Text (Text)

promote
  [d|

    pairVal :: Symbol -> Symbol -> Symbol
    pairVal "USD" "ZAR" = "USDZAR"
    pairVal "EUR" "ZAR" = "EURZAR"

    pairVals :: [(Symbol, Symbol)] -> [Symbol]
    pairVals = map (uncurry pairVal)

   |]

pairVal' :: forall a b p. (p ~ PairVal a b, SingI p) => Text
pairVal' = demote @p

pairVals' :: forall lst ps. (ps ~ PairVals lst, SingI ps) => [Text]
pairVals' = demote @ps

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ pairVal' @"USD" @"ZAR"
  print $ pairVals' @ '[ '("USD","ZAR"), '("EUR","ZAR") ]
```

Comment: To be pedantic, this actually came out much longer than the original class-based attempt :-)